# OrderBy and ThenBy with anonymous class

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have this:

```
List<string> lstRanksOrder = new List<string>() { 
  "Captain", "Lieutenant", "Sergeant", "Corporal Master", 
  "Corporal Senior", "Corporal 1", "Corporal", "Civilian Pilot" };

var emp = test
  .ToList()
  .Select(x => new
     {
       EID = x.IBM,
       Description = string.Format("{0} {1}", x.FirstName, x.LastName),
       Group = x.RPosition
     })
  .AsEnumerable()
  .OrderBy(x => lstRanksOrder.IndexOf(x.Group))
  .ThenBy(x => x.Description)
  .Distinct()
  .ToList();
```

The `ThenBy` Clause works fine, but is there a way to alter it to order by `LastName` before `FirstName` without changing the `Description` to `Description = string.Format("{0} {1}", x.LastName, x.FirstName)`?

Comment: Why not `.ThenBy(x => x.LastName).ThenBy(x => x.FirstName)` ?

Comment: why did you combine FirstName and LastName? new always gives you anonymous

Comment: yeah, put your `orderby` and `thenby` before the `select`

Comment: Your first `ToList` call should be an `AsEnumerable` call and your `AsEnumerable` call should be removed.

Comment: @SamIam And the `Distinct` before all of it.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.  I didn't think to sort the list before the anonymous class. So thank you again! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order the collection *before* calling the `Select` extension method:

```
var emp = test.ToList()
.OrderBy(x => lstRanksOrder.IndexOf(x.RPosition))
.ThenBy(x => x.LastName)
.ThenBy(x => x.FirstName)
.Select(x => new
{
    EID = x.IBM,
    Description = string.Format("{0} {1}", x.FirstName, x.LastName),
    Group = x.RPosition
})
.Distinct()
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Distinct` then `Order`  the collection before calling the `Select` extension method:

```
var emp = test.ToList()
.Distinct()
.OrderBy(x => lstRanksOrder.IndexOf(x.RPosition))
.ThenBy(x => x.LastName)
.ThenBy(x => x.FirstName)
.Select(x => new
{
    EID = x.IBM,
    Description = string.Format("{0} {1}", x.FirstName, x.LastName),
    Group = x.RPosition
})

.ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! much appreciated.